24.04 install issues
I've come across a couple of problems with the 24.04 install and I'm wondering if/how I should report them. I'm installing the latest version as of 2024-10-22, via a bootable USB drive (using rufus).
Two main issues:

The dialog asking whether to try Ubuntu or install it doesn't render properly. It's intermittent and a hard reset usually fixes it:



Attempting to read the 'First Report' on the 'Help improve Ubuntu' dialog causes a hang. Fixed by a hard reset and deselecting 'Share system data with the Ubuntu team'


Since this occurs so early in the (fresh) installation, I'm wondering if Ubuntu even know about the problems and the automatic reporting system won't catch them. Should I be reporting them?
